# How to generate different links on web page if JavaScript is enabled?

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript, graceful-degradation

I am trying to follow tecnhique of unobtrusive JavaScript / graceful degradation. I'd like to serve page with different links when JavaScript is turned on, and when JavaScript is turned off.

For example when JavaScript is turned off the link would be

```
<a href="script.cgi?a=action">
```

and when JavaScript is turned on

```
<a href="script.cgi?a=action;js=1">
```

(or something like that).

Both versions (with JavaScript and without JavaScript) of link lead to server side script, but with different parameters.  The version that is meant to be called when JavaScript is turned off performs more on server, therefore it would be unproductive to detect JavaScript there (e.g. redirecting from server script for non-JavaScript to the other version via `window.location`).

**Note:** I would prefer solution without using JavaScript libraries / frameworks like jQuery.

Comment: I don't like the brittleness of assuming the action querystring param will always be there. Why not a separate param, e.g., js=1?

Comment: The query string in the first example has an "a" parameter with a value of "action", the section example has the same but adds a "js" parameter with a value of "1". (Note that ; and & are interchangeable in all good query string handling libraries).

Comment: If you are following graceful degradation then you shouldn't be trying to inform the server that JS is available or not. It should be handled inside the page and the server shouldn't need to care. http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/ is a good guide.

Comment: @David Dorward: This may work for simple static (not generated) pages. However in my case it is a choice between doing all work on server (case A), and doing some work on client with JavaScript (and AJAX) and server doing _different_ work (case B).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the answer is to render the page as normal with the non-Javascript links. Then get the Javascript to replace the links with the JS=1 versions.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    links[i].href += ";js=1";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with the non-Javascript-enabled link, then simply use some Javascript code to modify the link to its Javascript-enabled value.  This ensures that the link will always be the correct version.  For example:

```
<a id="link_to_change" href="script.cgi?a=action">

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("link_to_change").href += ";js=1";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As long as they don't click the link before onload fires

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that intelligently handles links with no existing querystring.

```
// Get array of all links
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    // Add a question mark if link does not already have a querystring.
    links[i].href += (/\?/.test(links[i].href)) ? '' : '?';
    links[i].href += ';js=1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing one link, this should be enough:

```
<a href="script.cgi?a=action" onclick="this.href += ';js=1';">
```

Answer (score 0):

On my site, I develop a totally non-javascript version of the site. I develop in Django and pass down the data for the page as Django template variables. I render a page in a  tag, and then I JSONify the variables and render the javascript.

For example, here's the Django template for a mapview on my site:

```
{% extends "new-base.html" %} {% load markup %} {% load tb_tags %}

{% block headcontent %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var mapData = {{map|jsonify}};
  </script> 
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
  {% include "noscript/mapview.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

And here's the the noscript template that gets used. This is what people without JS and search engines use:

```
{% load tb_tags %}
<noscript>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/no-js.css"> 
  <style type="text/css"> div.content { padding:10px } </style>
  <div class=JSWhite>
    <h1 class=noJS>
      {% ifequal map.target.id map.places.0.node.id %}
        <a href="{{map.places.0.pages.0.url}}">{{map.target.name}}</a></h1>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{{map.target.url}}">{{map.target.name}}</a></h1>
      {% endifequal %}
    {% ifequal map.target.type 'node' %}
      &nbsp;- {{map.target.ele}} meters <BR>
    {% endifequal %}
    <span style ='color:gray; font-size:.8em; font-style:italic'>
      ({{map.target.la}},{{map.target.lo}})&nbsp;
    </span>
    <a class=JSAd target=_blank href=http://www.mytopo.com/searchgeo.cfm?lat={{map.target.la}}&lon={{map.target.lo}}&pid=trailbehind>Buy Topo Map</a> &nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <a style='font-size:.8em;color:#CC5500' target=_blank href='http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q={{map.target.name}}'>Get Directions</a>
    {% if map.target.dist %}
      <BR>{{map.target.dist}}
    {% endif %}
    {% if map.target.ascent %}
      <BR>{{map.target.ascent}}
    {% endif %}

    {% for r in map.places %}
      {% ifequal r.node.id map.target.id %} 
        <BR>
        {% if r.pages.0 %}
          {{r.pages.0.summary}}
        {% endif %}
        <UL style='list-style:none;margin-left:0; padding-left:0'>
          {% for key in r.pages %}
            {% ifnotequal forloop.counter 1 %}
              <LI><a href={{key.url}}>{{key.title}}</a><BR>
                  {{key.snippet}}
              </LI>
            {% endifnotequal %}
          {% endfor %}
        </UL>
     {% endifequal %}
   {% endfor %}
   <HR>
   <strong>(<a href="{{map.target.url}}">All</a> -
     <a href="{{map.target.url}}hiking/">Hiking</a> -
     <a href="{{map.target.url}}camping/">Camping</a> - 
     <a href="{{map.target.url}}climbing/">Climbing</a> - 
     <a href="{{map.target.url}}biking/">Biking</a>)</strong><BR>
  <p>
  {% if map.places %}
    <h1>Nearby Adventures</h1>
    <UL style='list-style:none;margin:0; margin-top:10px;padding-left:0'>
      {% for r in map.places %}
        {% ifnotequal r.node.id map.target.id %} 
          <LI><h1>
      {% if r.node.trip_id %}
        <a href="{{r.node.url}}">{{r.pages.0.title}}</a></h1>
      {% else %}
       <a href="{{r.node.url}}{{activity}}">{{r.pages.0.title}}</a></h1>
          {% endif %}
      {% if r.pages.0 %}
            {% if r.pages.0.activity %}
          <strong>{{r.pages.0.activity}}</strong> -
            {% endif %}
            {{r.pages.0.snippet}}
     {% endif %}
   {% endifnotequal %}
     {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   </UL>
   </p>
  </div>
</noscript>
```